# How can identical beacons have unique BTLE Addresses?

Tags: ios, btle

If there are multiple identical BTLE beacons within range of an IOS device, how can they be differentiated without programming each beacon with a unique MAC?

Answer (score 1):

If the beacon advertisements are identical and the MAC's are identical, you can't differentiate them. Generally BLE beacons should each have a unique MAC.